# Tab Controller Views's first Tab is black - Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, tabs

I currently have a Tab Controller that has 4 child tab views. (Seen below)

[image]

Each "tab" view has only a navigation bar at the top and a button in the middle.

All of these work correctly except for the first one, which renders with no Navigation bar and a blank background (ignoring any of the content placed on the View).

I've checked all of the View controllers and there identical, so i don't understand why the first tab won't display correctly?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't worked much with TabControllers, but do you need to set the initial tab when the ViewLoads?

Comment: That's something I thought, but could find no documentation on how to actually do it.

Comment: I would suggest using `UINavigationController` for each of the tab views. You would have to provide some code for more assistance.

Comment: Lewis, Sorry But I have a question: What is the scheme on your image ? How I can create this in Xamarin?